# Ordinary user can read /etc/passwd. Is it a a security hole?

Tags: permissions

When check the /etc/passwd file permissions, I discover that all user have the read permission to it.

```
$ ls -l /etc/passwd
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 3381 2015-11-04 11:02 /etc/passwd
```

Is it a security hole? Why or why not?

Comment: There is no password in it, no sensitive information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it a security hole? Why or why not?

No, it isn't. `/etc/passwd` should be readonly to users (-rw-r--r--). It is sometimes called the user database. That should give us a clue as to why it needs to be readable by everyone. Any utility that inspects file metadata needs to be able to read `/etc/passwd` (and so `/etc/group`) in order to be able to resolve the numerical IDs used by the kernel and its subsystems to the human-friendly names that we rely on. Tools that need to find your home directory look that information up in `/etc/passwd`, and inet miniservers like `fingers` look up your details in `/etc/passwd`.

As has been pointed out elsewhere, there is no particularly sensitive data in the file, as modern systems put the password hashes in `/etc/shadow` file, which is readonly by root.